# Unable to import Fancybox on Shopify site. Jquery loaded only once

Tags: jquery, fancybox, shopify, liquid

I've added fancy box (found here: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/) to my shopify site using the Narrative theme, but I am getting the error:

```
VM3024:1 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fancybox is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:22
```

This is often an indication that Jquery is being loaded multiple times. Maybe I'm overlooking it, but I don't see it being loaded more than once. Maybe the default Shopify Analytics is loading it?

The full source to my website can be seen here:

`view-source:https://www.beckahsheeler.com/`

In order to import fancy box, I added the following to my theme template all of which are located in my assets folder and loaded fine, which you can see by following the paths in my website's source.

```
{{ 'jquery-latest.min.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
{{ 'jquery.fancybox.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
{{ 'jquery.fancybox.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
```

What am I doing that causes `fancybox()` to not be recognized as a function?

Answer (score 0):

You should contact the author of your theme, because file `theme.min.js` contains a modified copy of jQuery. Since this is minified version, it is not possible to tell what exactly is going on here (if you would prettify that file, you would find `window.$ = window.jQuery = $n` and that $n seems to be an extended version of jQuery v3.1.0).

Also, you try to include jQuery from `jquery-latest.min.js` that actually contains v1.11.1, but if you run `jQuery.fn.jquery` on your page, it returns v3.1.0. So, it gets somehow overwritten and I suspect that your theme file has something to do with that.